# If All Contacts are deleted will tracking still be retained?

Tags: marketing-cloud

Looking to delete all contacts from Marketing Cloud and bring in all new subscribers through the MC Connect. Will I lose previous tracking on emails?

If there's an easy way to merge contacts with their new MC Connect counterparts if they exist, I would do that method but otherwise, deleting all and re-importing is most likely my route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tracking data will remain in the system but in an anonymized format and cannot be linked to a specific record.

Source: [Tracking in Email Studio](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_tracking_overview.htm&type=5)

Keep in mind that contact deletion process does not apply to non-sendable data extensions that are not included in population via Data Designer.

Source: [Contact Deletion in Contact Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_contact_deletion.htm&type=5)

Comment: Would you recommend exporting the data prior to deletion if we would like to link specific records?

Comment: Sure, Salesforce recommends exporting the data to re-import optins after the deletion process.

Comment: Can you mark this as an answer please?